# fetchmail doesn't get mail from provider

Tags: linux, postfix, fetchmail, exchange

somehow can't get fetchmail to work properly... it wont get email from provider but it connects to properly

```
# Configuration created Tue Feb 10 10:18:32 2015 by fetchmailconf 1.52 $Revision: 4636 $ set postmaster "adm@domain.com"
#set nobouncemail
#set no spambounce
#set properties ""
#set daemon 900 poll mail.domain.com with proto POP3 localdomains domain.com
    envelope X-Originally-To
    user 'user' with password 'pass' to * here options smtphost  192.168.15.150
```

```
fetchmail: WARNING: Running as root is discouraged.
fetchmail: 6.3.2 querying mail.domain.com (protocol POP3) at Tue Feb 10 10:38:09 2015: poll started
fetchmail: POP3< +OK POP3 server ready <848591453.795682759@mail.domain.com>
fetchmail: POP3> CAPA
fetchmail: POP3< -ERR bad command
fetchmail: bad command
fetchmail: Repoll immediately on user@mailns.domain.com
fetchmail: POP3< +OK POP3 server ready <2108898658.1799016658@mail.domain.com>
fetchmail: POP3> USER user
fetchmail: POP3< +OK
fetchmail: POP3> PASS *
fetchmail: POP3< +OK connected
fetchmail: POP3> STAT
fetchmail: POP3< +OK 1 3255
fetchmail: POP3> LAST
fetchmail: POP3< -ERR bad command
fetchmail: bad command
fetchmail: POP3> UIDL
fetchmail: POP3< +OK listing follows
fetchmail: POP3< 1 15021010380695
fetchmail: POP3< .
1 message for user at mail.domain.com (3255 octets).
fetchmail: POP3> LIST 1
fetchmail: POP3< -ERR message 1 not found
fetchmail: message 1 not found
fetchmail: POP3> QUIT
fetchmail: POP3< +OK
fetchmail: client/server protocol error while fetching from user@mail.domain.com
fetchmail: 6.3.2 querying mail.domain.com (protocol POP3) at Tue Feb 10 10:38:09 2015: poll completed
fetchmail: Query status=4 (PROTOCOL)
fetchmail: normal termination, status 4
Done.
```

Answer (score 2):

Your mail server is broken.  It claims that it has a message numbered 1 in the UIDL command, but then the LIST command trying to get the size of that message claims there is no such message.

Comment: but there are messages because if i use another client (efs in windows) it works just fine

Comment: @vartaxe, yes... the server says there is a message... but then it says there isn't, so it's broken.

Comment: hum ok so that should be my postfix? how to tell? because i can send mail with mutt client to my exchange server :/

Comment: or perhaps ISP postfix has issues could this be possible?

Comment: @vartaxe, whatever the POP3 server you are connecting to is where the problem is... I have no idea if that is yours, or your ISP's, or whether it is running postfix or some other software.

Answer (score 0):

Some POP3 servers are missing the LIST command.
This command indeed gives the size of each mail available.
To avoid this check, and to find a path to restore the service, just use the fetchmail "fetchsizelimit" option and set it to 0.

> fetchsizelimit 0

This way, fetchmail doesn't care about sizes any more and skips the use of the LIST command. Problem solved.